# Hanoi towers time exeeded

Tags: c++, performance, recursion

I am having problem with a simple Hanoi tower program.  I need to do something to reduce its time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int hanojus(int n, char a, char b, char c) {

    ofstream fr("hanoj.out",ios::app);
    if (n == 1)
        fr<<a<< " -> " <<c<<endl;
    else {
         hanojus(n-1, a, c, b);
         fr<<a<< " -> " <<c<<endl;
         hanojus(n-1, b, a, c);
        }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream fd("hanoj.in");
    int sk;
    fd>>sk;
    hanojus(sk, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try moving the ofstream outside of the method so that you're not creating it every time you make a recursive call.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int hanojus(int n, char a, char b, char c, ofstream& fr)
{
    if (n == 1)
        fr<<a<< " -> " <<c<<endl;
    else
    {
        hanojus(n-1, a, c, b, fr);
        fr<<a<< " -> " <<c<<endl;
        hanojus(n-1, b, a, c, fr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fd("hanoj.in");
    ofstream fr("hanoj.out",ios::app);
    int sk;
    fd>>sk;
    hanojus(sk, 'A', 'B', 'C', fr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The most efficient is to use non-recursive algorithm.
   You can read about it in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Non-recursive_solution).

   Time: [image] Same as recursive algorithm

   Memory: [image] Unlike the recursive version, the configuration of the 
   rings must be explicitly represented; it suffices to use 3 stacks, each 
   holding a maximum of n rings.

   Note: to store stack it is better to use `std::vector` or static array instead of `std::stack`.
2. You can use C-style io. It often works faster. Do not create output stream each time (if you use recursive algorithm).
3. If you compile your code, use `-O2` or `-O3` to create more optimized program.

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if well used streams are significantly slower than the C family of IO. Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17468320/567864